$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos^m\frac{2\pi k}{n}$
Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $m$ be a positive even number such that $n>2$ and $n>m$. Show that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos^m\frac{2\pi k}{n}=\frac{(m-1)!!}{m!!}n.
$$

Do you have any ideas with this question?

As an FYI: MSE is not a "do my work for me" site. Such posts (e.g. "PSQs") are in poor taste, downvoted, & closed; we expect users to put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. relevant definitions, your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If needed: this is useful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 helps find past questions.

When $m$ is odd, I can prove the sum is $0$ by using complex numbers. When $m$ is even, I don’t know what to do.

The sum is $$\sum \cos^m\frac{2\pi k}{n}=\sum_k (\frac{e^{2\pi i k/n}+e^{-2\pi i k/n}}{2})^m=\sum_{k,l}\binom{m}{l}e^{2\pi i k(2l-m)/n}/2^m$$ since $n>m$ and $2l-m$ varies from $-m$ to $m$, so if $l\neq m/2$ then $e^{2\pi i (2l-m)/n}\neq 1$, as a consequence
$\sum_k e^{2\pi i k(2l-m)/n}$ is zero.
So the only contribution comes from $l=m/2$ and the sum is $$n\binom{m}{m/2}\frac{1}{2^m}=\frac{(m-1)!!}{m!!}n$$

Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.
